# WPF Ribbon 4.0 - Size definition at control level

Tags: wpf, ribbon

I have defined something like this

```
<ribbon:RibbonGroup Header="Size at Control Level">
                    <ribbon:RibbonControlGroup>
                        <ribbon:RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images\wizard-icon16.png" LargeImageSource="Images\wizard-icon32.png" Label="Button 1">
                            <ribbon:RibbonButton.ControlSizeDefinition>
                                <ribbon:RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Large" IsLabelVisible="True"></ribbon:RibbonControlSizeDefinition>
                            </ribbon:RibbonButton.ControlSizeDefinition>
                        </ribbon:RibbonButton>
                        <ribbon:RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images\wizard-icon16.png" LargeImageSource="Images\wizard-icon32.png" Label="Button 2">
                            <ribbon:RibbonButton.ControlSizeDefinition>
                                <ribbon:RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Small" IsLabelVisible="True"></ribbon:RibbonControlSizeDefinition>
                            </ribbon:RibbonButton.ControlSizeDefinition>
                        </ribbon:RibbonButton>
                        <ribbon:RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images\wizard-icon16.png" LargeImageSource="Images\wizard-icon32.png" Label="Button 3"></ribbon:RibbonButton>
                        <ribbon:RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images\wizard-icon16.png" LargeImageSource="Images\wizard-icon32.png" Label="Button 4"></ribbon:RibbonButton>
                    </ribbon:RibbonControlGroup>
                </ribbon:RibbonGroup>
```

But all the buttons are large. Even if I set a ControlSizeDefinition property with Small for all the controls, they still are large. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

From [MSDN: Ribbon Layout and Resizing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701790.aspx) (about halfway down the page in small text):

> Control Groups
>
> Related ribbon controls can be grouped together in a
>   RibbonControlGroup. When a control group is resized, **one
>   RibbonControlSizeDefinition is applied to all of the controls in the
>   RibbonControlGroup**. The RibbonControlGroup is positioned in the
>   RibbonGroup as if it were one control.

So if multiple RibbonButtons are in a common `RibbonControlGroup` (as your example shows) then they will always share the same RibbonControlSizeDefinition. In the current state of the WPF Ribbon, you will not be able to specify different sizes. You would need to group them differently to achieve such an effect. (maybe putting them in a stackpanel wrapped within a border... but I fear that putting non-ribbon controls onto the ribbon sometimes ruins the nice built in features of the ribbon).

I suspect you really don't intend to put all four of your buttons within a single control group. A `RibbonControlGroup` is intended to 'glue very closely related buttons together' so there is 0 spacing between where one button ends and the next begins. This doesn't work well for buttons of different size. I think you may just want your buttons to be placed directly in the Ribbon Group, as that should really be the container that tells a user that the buttons are related somehow.

An additional side note: You can specify a size definition on the RibbonControlGroup that will apply to all four of your buttons within it like so:

```
<ribbon:RibbonGroup Header="Size at Control Level">
    <ribbon:RibbonControlGroup>
        <ribbon:RibbonControlGroup.ControlSizeDefinition>
            <r:RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Small" IsLabelVisible="False" />
        </ribbon:RibbonControlGroup.ControlSizeDefinition>
        <ribbon:RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images\wizard-icon16.png" LargeImageSource="Images\wizard-icon32.png" Label="Button 1" />
        <ribbon:RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images\wizard-icon16.png" LargeImageSource="Images\wizard-icon32.png" Label="Button 2" />
        <ribbon:RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images\wizard-icon16.png" LargeImageSource="Images\wizard-icon32.png" Label="Button 3" />
        <ribbon:RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images\wizard-icon16.png" LargeImageSource="Images\wizard-icon32.png" Label="Button 4" />
    </ribbon:RibbonControlGroup>
</ribbon:RibbonGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set the `SmallImageSource` and don't set the `LargeImageSource`, the button should default to the small size.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong.  The ribbon toolbar is automatically scaling your images up.  If it runs of space, it will use the smaller images for the ones you designate as small, and continue using the larger images for the ones you designate as large.  But, if there's room to display large images, it will do that if it can.

You should see this behavior as you fill up your ribbon bar.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Scotts answer, but with this you could define the size of the RibbonButtons independently, not only the group items size.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8601891/9758687